# How can I get baseadapter to start at a different position than 0 or 1

Tags: java, android-listview, baseadapter, getview

I have a baseadapter and it always starts at position 0 or 1 at the very top but is there someway that I can make my Baseadapter start at position 5? I been searching on here and have not found information on that, this is my baseadapter and yes it is connected to a listview but I know that the position that the listview starts is controlled by the BaseAdapter

```
public class myadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater myiflater;
    public myadapter() {

        myiflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
  return 20;



    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

// all of this is already correct
        } 
catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
          }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried to set the starting position at 5 but it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this with your ListView:

```
mListView.setSelection(5);
```

[setSelection()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)) sets the current position of the ListView via the adapter. The way you are trying doesn't make sense. For the getItem() method you are supposed to return the object, not a numerical value for position. Let me know if that works

Comment: Right on, now problem glad to help!